# Spring 3.1 NoClassDefFoundError ListableBeanFactory

Tags: eclipse, spring, build, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to upgrade an old project from Spring 2.5.6 to Spring 3.1.0. The project is not built with Maven so I had to add the jars manually to the build path.

The application uses Eclipse RAP as well as Spring.

I added all the Spring 3.1 jars in my build path:

```
lib/org.springframework.aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
lib/org.springframework.asm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
lib/org.springframework.aspects-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
lib/org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
lib/org.springframework.context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
lib/org.springframework.context.support-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
lib/org.springframework.core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
lib/org.springframework.expression-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
lib/org.springframework.instrument-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
lib/org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
lib/org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
lib/org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
lib/org.springframework.orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
lib/org.springframework.oxm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
lib/org.springframework.test-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
lib/org.springframework.transaction-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
lib/org.springframework.web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
lib/org.springframework.web.portlet-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
lib/org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
lib/org.springframework.web.struts-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
```

and I also listed them in the MANIFEST.MF.

The project builds fine, but at runtime when trying to login it gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory
```

I looked in the beans jar and the class is definitely there. I also searched through the project and the class is not used explicitly anywhere.

What could cause this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This class does not exist in Spring 3.1.0. See http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.springframework.beans.factory.ListableBeanFactory

Comment: In which jar exactly does the method exist?